# error when using closest() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can only press delete button once for deletion of each `li`. Why is this happening?

```
<input type="text" placeholder ="Add List" id="listItem"/>
<button id="addButton">add Item</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>


$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#addButton').click(function(){
        var listItem = '<li>' + $('#listItem').val();
        listItem += '<button id = "deleteButton">Delete</button';
        listItem += '</li>';
        $('#output').append(listItem);

        $('#deleteButton').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ID of an element must be unique, so use class to group similar elements. Also use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addButton').click(function () {
        var listItem = '<li>' + $('#listItem').val();
        listItem += '<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button';
        listItem += '</li>';
        $('#output').append(listItem);
    });
    $('#output').on('click', '.deleteButton', function () {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cv6pc/)

When you use id-selector it will fetch only the first element with the said ID.

Answer (score 0):

Since your button has been added dynamically, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach click event to these newly added delete buttons:

```
$('#output').on('click', '.deleteButton', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Btw, `id` is unique you should use `class` instead for your button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#addButton').click(function(){
        var listItem = '<li>' + $('#listItem').val();
        listItem += '<button id = "deleteButton">Delete</button';
        listItem += '</li>';
        $('#output').append(listItem);
    });

    $('#output').on('click', '.deleteButton', function () {
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder ="Add List" id="listItem"/>
<button id="addButton">add Item</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

**JS code:**

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    var listItem = '<li>' + $('#listItem').val();
    listItem += '<button class = "deleteButton">Delete</button';
    listItem += '</li>';
    $('#output').append(listItem);
});

$('.deleteButton').live('click',function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QFR5f/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#addButton').unbind("click").click(function(){
        var listItem = '<li>' + $('#listItem').val();
        listItem += '<button class = "deleteButton">Delete</button>';
        listItem += '</li>';
        $('#output').append(listItem);

        $('.deleteButton').click(function() {
            console.log($(this).closest('li'))
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

You are assigning same id to all the delete buttons that's where the issue is.

Note - Although HTML does not protest on multiple elements elements having the same id, but we should not have. :)